# Webpack and External Dynamic Loading

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, webpack, externals

I'm trying to get webpack to load externals dynamically. I'm having trouble because the file names are only set at run time. I have put together a simple sample project:

https://github.com/jamesdalel/webpackdynamicimport

I have looked around and I can't really find an solutions for this problem. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

I just get an can't find file error. This is because webpack is unaware of this when bundling. I'm trying load it at runtime here.

Thanks, James

Comment: What errors do you get? Compile error? Runtime error?

Comment: Hi, I get errors at run time when I try and do the dynamic import.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that webpack isn't capable of doing that form of imports, which renders the complete concept of "dynamic" importing unusable. Did you make any progress with that?